# Rest service proxy accessing error using GWT

Tags: web-services, rest, gwt, proxy

I have a Rest web service. I access it by using a java application and its package structure is given below.

src.app ->App.gwt.xml

src.app.source->RestProxyClass.java// to access the Rest Application

Following is App.gwt.xml file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="App">
    <source path="source"/>
</module>
```

Using this java application I can access Rest web service.

I took this projects jar and add to GWT project. I add this jar file to library and select the jar from Order and Export. I got this package in Referenced Libraries

then I add this following code in .gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name="app.App" />
```

But run time I got the following error :

```
No source code is available for type app.source.RestProxyClass; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Following is GWT code

```
public class RestProxyAccessClient implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
RestProxyClass app=new RestProxyClass();
        try {
            //restProxy.check();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please help.. I didn't get answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `*.java` files are packaged within the JAR.